# How to use copy_to do multi field aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I put some data into ES. Then I specify two field in one group using copy_to feature. The reason to do this is to do multi field agg. Below are my steps.

## Create index

```
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/test?pretty" -d '{
"mappings" : {
    "type9k" : {
        "properties" : {
            "SRC" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" ,"copy_to": "SRC_AND_DST"},
            "DST" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" ,"copy_to": "SRC_AND_DST"},
            "BITS" : { "type" : "long", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
            "TIME" : { "type" : "long", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
        }
    }
}
```

}'

## Put data into ES

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/test/type9k/_bulk?pretty" -d '
{"index":{}}
{"SRC":"BJ","DST":"DL","PROTOCOL":"ip","BITS":10,"TIME":1453360000}
{"index":{}}
{"SRC":"BJ","DST":"DL","PROTOCOL":"tcp","BITS":10,"TIME":1453360000}
{"index":{}}
{"SRC":"DL","DST":"SH","PROTOCOL":"UDP","BITS":10,"TIME":1453360000}
{"index":{}}
{"SRC":"SH","DST":"BJ","PROTOCOL":"ip","BITS":10,"TIME":1453360000}
{"index":{}}
{"SRC":"BJ","DST":"DL","PROTOCOL":"ip","BITS":20,"TIME":1453360300}
{"index":{}}
{"SRC":"BJ","DST":"SH","PROTOCOL":"tcp","BITS":20,"TIME":1453360300}
{"index":{}}
{"SRC":"DL","DST":"SH","PROTOCOL":"UDP","BITS":20,"TIME":1453360300}
{"index":{}}
{"SRC":"SH","DST":"BJ","PROTOCOL":"ip","BITS":20,"TIME":1453360300}
{"index":{}}
{"SRC":"BJ","DST":"DL","PROTOCOL":"ip","BITS":30,"TIME":1453360600}
{"index":{}}
{"SRC":"BJ","DST":"SH","PROTOCOL":"tcp","BITS":30,"TIME":1453360600}
{"index":{}}
{"SRC":"DL","DST":"SH","PROTOCOL":"UDP","BITS":30,"TIME":1453360600}
{"index":{}}
{"SRC":"SH","DST":"BJ","PROTOCOL":"ip","BITS":30,"TIME":1453360600}
'
```

## OK. Question

I want to aggregate on SRC,DST use sum aggregator. Then return the top 3 results. Translate my requirement to SQL is like

```
SELECT sum(BITS) FROM table GROUP BY src,dst ORDER BY sum(BITS) DESC LIMIT 3.
```

I know that I can do this using script feature like below:

```
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/_all/_search?pretty" -d '
{
  "_source": [ "SRC", "DST","BITS"],
  "size":0,
  "query": {  "match_all": {} },
  "aggs":
    {
      "SRC_DST": 
        {
          "terms": {"script": "[doc.SRC.value, doc.DST.value].join(\"-\")","size": 2,"shard_size":0, "order": {"sum_bits": "desc"}},
          "aggs": { "sum_bits": { "sum": {"field": "BITS"} } }
        }
    }
}
'
```

The result I got with script will be like below:

```
"aggregations" : {
"SRC_DST" : {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count" : 10,
  "buckets" : [ {
    "key" : "BJ-DL",
    "doc_count" : 8,
    "sum_bits" : {
      "value" : 140.0
    }
  }, {
    "key" : "DL-SH",
    "doc_count" : 6,
    "sum_bits" : {
      "value" : 120.0
    }
  } ]
```

But I`m expecting to do it with **copy_to** feature. Because I think scripting may cost too much time.

Comment: It is unclear what kind of aggregation you are trying to do. The Sum Aggregation is for numeric data, but your SRC and DST fields store String data. Also, the `copy_to` should have no bearing on the types of aggregations you can use nor how aggregating is done. `copy_to` simple copies the data from one field to another at indexing time. Please clarify your question with an example of the type of aggregation results you are aiming for. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Brooke. Thanks I have re-edited my question. I added a SQL statement to describe my question.

Comment: are you looking to aggregate on combination of SRC+DST like BJ-DL, SH-BJ etc or nested aggregation? is it possible for you to edit your question with sample output?

Comment: Thanks, I now understand what you are trying to accomplish. However, I don't think `copy_to` is going to help you achieve what you are aiming at if you are trying to avoid using scripting. Do you have the ability to modify your data before putting it into ES?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 , I give some sample output and also the query json using script feature. I`m hoping that I can get the same result with copy_to feature.

Comment: @BrookeB Hi, I can modify my data before putting into ES. But this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_multi_field_terms_aggregation It said we can make it with _copy_to .    **"If you know ahead of time that you want to collect the terms from two or more fields, then use copy_to in your mapping to create a new dedicated field at index time which contains the values from both fields. You can aggregate on this single field, which will benefit from the global ordinals optimization."**

Comment: If you can modify your data before inserting, that is by far the best solution. Create a new field which stores the concatenation of SRC and DEST and use a terms agg on it. `copy_to` is only useful if you were grouping by individual terms from multiple fields, but you are grouping on pairs of terms.

Comment: @BrookeB is right, I think you have misunderstood the `copy_to` functionality, it does not `combine` field values. You need to do something like [transform](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-transform.html), but dont use it as it is deprecated, write your own while indexing. Also script might be too slow if you have lot of values.

Comment: @ChintanShah25 and BrookeB . Thanks very much for your answers. I also noticed that there is a feature called warm up. In my understanding this should be something like a index in relational database. Do you think it will help to speed up my query If I create a warm up for the script solution?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with index warmers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I guess you do not need `copy_to` functionality. If I go by `SQL query` then what you are asking can be done with [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and [sum aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) like this

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_src": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "SRC",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "unique_dst": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "DST",
            "size": 3,
            "order": {
              "bits_sum": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "bits_sum": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "BITS"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Above query give me output like this

```
"aggregations": {
      "unique_src": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "BJ",
               "doc_count": 6,
               "unique_dst": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "DL",
                        "doc_count": 4,
                        "bits_sum": {
                           "value": 70
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "SH",
                        "doc_count": 2,
                        "bits_sum": {
                           "value": 50
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "DL",
               "doc_count": 3,
               "unique_dst": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "SH",
                        "doc_count": 3,
                        "bits_sum": {
                           "value": 60
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "SH",
               "doc_count": 3,
               "unique_dst": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "BJ",
                        "doc_count": 3,
                        "bits_sum": {
                           "value": 60
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Thanks. Your query is fine but the result can not be sorted by ES. I have to sort by myself then return the top N result. I have give a sample query using script feature. I want to get the same result use copy_to feature